# How can I switch two keyboard buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I wanted it so that every time the spacebar is pressed (keyCode 32) the computer reads it as the letter A being pressed (keyCode 65), how would I go about doing that?

say I wanted there to be an input and every time the person puts in a it becomes b.

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input> </input>



<script>

document.onkeydown = function(event)
{
     var x = event.keyCode;

     if(x == 65)
     {
         x = x + 1;
     }


}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's part of a riddle game where the secret message is encoded. for example if the person types in "vnbbl" it would come out as "hello" meaning v is h, n is e, etc.

Comment: Why would you need this....?

Comment: I dont think that this is possible. You want to change this behaviour only in your current tab? or in the whole system? It would be good if you can add the reason why you want this, maybe there's a better aproach to solve your problem

Comment: The whole system. I would run it on a nodejs program like electron.

Comment: you can't switch the buttons, but you can build that behaviour by `onKeyDown -> event.preventDefault()` and `input.value += encodedCharacter[ event.keyCode ]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to make the program register the keys differently.

Technically you could just change the `x` variable like so:

```
document.onkeydown = function (event){
    var x = event.keyCode;
    x = (x + 33) % 126; 
    // 33 is the difference between 32 and 65;
    // 126 is the total number of keyCodes
}
```

Using a formula like this, however, will result in non-alphanumeric characters in your string. (Such as `~`)

Answer (score 0):

Is your source element an text input element? Not sure about cheating the computer, but maybe changing the element value, like this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event)
{
   var x = event.keyCode;
   //source element
   var elem = event.target;

   if(x == 32)
   {
      //replacing all " " with "a", this is case sensitive, ok? so "A" and "a" are different situations...
      elem.value = elem.split(' ').join('a');
   }
}
```